# NoClassDefFoundError while trying to run unit tests on Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to create some simple tests for my Android app but I'm running into issues with getting the tests to even run. I keep getting a NoClassDefFound error while I'm trying to run the test, however I can't seem to figure out what the cause of it is. I'd appreciate it if I could get a fresh pair of eyes to look at this.

EDIT: Here is a picture of the structure:

[image: Link]

Here's the error that I keep getting:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testScanResultNotNull (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nl.hanze.myhealth.ScanResultActivity
at nl.hanze.myhealth.CameraTest.<init>(CameraTest.java:14)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getTest(BaseTestRunner.java:118)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.getTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:149)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.setTestClassName(AndroidTestRunner.java:57)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTestClassByName(TestSuiteBuilder.java:80)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClass(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:443)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClasses(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:424)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:370)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4435)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

CameraTest

```
package nl.hanze.myhealth;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;

    public class CameraTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ScanResultActivity> {

        ScanResultActivity mActivity;

        public CameraTest(){
            super(ScanResultActivity.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void setUp()throws Exception{
            super.setUp();
            mActivity = getActivity();
        }

        @SmallTest
        public void testScanResultNotNull(){
            boolean test = mActivity.generateScanResult();
            assertNotNull(test);
        }

        @Override
        protected void tearDown() throws Exception{
            super.tearDown();
        }
    }
```

ScanResultActivity

```
package nl.hanze.myhealth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.Random;


    public class ScanResultActivity extends Activity {

        Random rand = new Random();

        public ScanResultActivity(){

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_result);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.scan_result, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        protected boolean generateScanResult(){
            boolean positive_scanresult;
            int max = 10;
            int min = 1;
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            if(randomNum >= 6){
                positive_scanresult = true;
            }else{
                positive_scanresult = false;
            }
            return positive_scanresult;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you running as Android test and not JUnit test?

Comment: @helleye I believe I am running the tests as Android tests, yes.

Comment: From the code it seems your test class is in `package nl.hanze.myhealth;`, and not in a test package.

Comment: @helleye I've included a picture of the structure in the OP. The androidTest folder was generated by Android Studio.

Comment: The error states: `(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nl.hanze.myhealthtests.ScanResultActivity)`. So where do you have nl.hanze.myhealthtests defined?

Comment: @helleye Well, here's the thing: I tried renaming the packages containing the tests to a different one but for some reason that ended up renaming both packages to healthtests. The error was just from when I still had both renamed to healthtests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Put your tests into package **nl.hanze.myhealth.tests**.
You can do so using Android Studio, or manually:

- create a new folder **tests** inside ...\app\src\androidTest\java\nl\hanze\myhealth\
- move ApplicationTest.java and CameraTest.java inside ...\app\src\androidTest\java\nl\hanze\myhealth\tests\
- rename the package name in each of your java test files to
  **package nl.hanze.myhealth.tests;**

2) In you application's **build.gradle** you need to have:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nl.hanze.myhealth"
    testApplicationId "nl.hanze.myhealth.tests"
    ...
}
```

Rebuild and run. That should be enough.

Comment: Good luck with the writing of tests. I have a lot of problems with them lately :)

Comment: I don't see why renaming the tests package was necessary or why it worked. This is generally not necessary. The tests are usually in the same package as the classes under test.

Comment: @AdilHussain, Yes, the last couple of times I wrote tests it was working without renaming the test package. I guess some updates have been done meanwhile in the toolchain.

Answer (score 11):

This happened to me as well, not sure if it was for the same reason as you but what fixed it for me was a simple `File->Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: re-sync gradle also fixed my issue

Answer (score 8):

I started getting this error suddenly in Android Studio running tests as packages (JUnit/Robolectric3/Gradle) and had no idea why. I was able to run the test files independently just fine, but I got the NoClassDefFoundError exception when running all tests together inside of a package.

Turns out the classpath during runtime wasnt loading classes correctly. The issue could not be reproduced on another machine.

To fix it, I deleted my project .idea folder and .iml files, then reimported the whole Gradle project to Android Studio. Then it worked!

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, additionally I found that some of the module dependencies may have been incorrectly configured. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319185