# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, testing, gradle

I have split my project into two modules: app and domain, there should be more for clean-architecture, but I have met a problem before I want to move forward.

I have added a new module `:domain:` and added a `test` folder inside, and moved my tests from the `:app` module into this folder. Unfortunately while testing the file I have met the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lbel/mobile/domain/interactor/accounts/GetAccountList;

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.<init>(DefaultInternalRunner.java:27)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.<init>(DefaultInternalRunner.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.util.RunnerProvider.newInstance(RunnerProvider.java:27)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.RunnerFactory.create(RunnerFactory.java:69)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.RunnerFactory.createStrict(RunnerFactory.java:40)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.<init>(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:152)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bel.mobile.domain.interactor.accounts.GetAccountList
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 33 more
```

Here is my build.gradle file for module domain:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$project.ext.rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "junit:junit:$project.ext.junitVersion"
    implementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$project.ext.mockitoVersion"
    implementation "com.google.truth:truth:$project.ext.truthVersion"
}
```

Here is **domain.iml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id=":domain" external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/.." external.system.id="GRADLE" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android-gradle" name="Android-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":domain" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
    <facet type="java-gradle" name="Java-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="BUILD_FOLDER_PATH" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
        <option name="BUILDABLE" value="true" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
    <facet type="kotlin-language" name="Kotlin">
      <configuration version="3" platform="JVM 1.8" useProjectSettings="false">
        <compilerSettings />
        <compilerArguments>
          <option name="destination" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/kotlin/main" />
          <option name="noStdlib" value="true" />
          <option name="noReflect" value="true" />
          <option name="moduleName" value="domain" />
          <option name="jvmTarget" value="1.8" />
          <option name="addCompilerBuiltIns" value="true" />
          <option name="loadBuiltInsFromDependencies" value="true" />
          <option name="languageVersion" value="1.2" />
          <option name="apiVersion" value="1.2" />
          <option name="pluginOptions">
            <array />
          </option>
          <option name="pluginClasspaths">
            <array />
          </option>
        </compilerArguments>
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/java/main" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/java/test" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/kotlin" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/kotlin" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.gradle" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="rxjava-2.1.6" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.10" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="truth-0.39" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="junit-4.12" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="mockito-core-2.8.9" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="reactive-streams-1.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.10" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="kotlin-stdlib-1.2.10" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="hamcrest-core-1.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="byte-buddy-1.6.14" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="byte-buddy-agent-1.6.14" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="objenesis-2.5" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="guava-23.4-android" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="error_prone_annotations-2.1.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="annotations-13.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="jsr305-1.3.9" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="j2objc-annotations-1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="PROVIDED" name="animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

What I have tried to do so far:

- I have tried many different ways and checked many solutions regarding the same error to solve the problem, but none of them fix it
- I have checked that simple test is working inside of this folder.
- I have added Multidex

**Update**:

Also in the **build/reports/../index.html** file I have the report that all test are 100% successful. And that is new tests, done after initing some of the command under **:domain** module, from from Gradle tab on the right side of Android Studio.

Comment: were you able to figure out the solution, i am stuck on the same problem ;(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? [NoClassDefFoundError while trying to run unit tests on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892503/noclassdeffounderror-while-trying-to-run-unit-tests-on-android-studio)

Specifically

> 2) In you application's build.gradle you need to have:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "bel.mobile.domain"
    testApplicationId "bel.mobile.domain.test"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. Unfortunately, that does not help.